# How to get a list of elements from a list of tuples?

Tags: haskell

How to get an element inside of a list of tuples?
For example

```
list = [(Tris, 23, 1.40), (Aif, 20 , 1.70)]
```

I want all the ages

```
[23,20]
```

I know that I can use

```
age = (_,x,_) = x
```

But it only works with tuples and not a tuple inside a list.

Comment: You probably mean: `age (_, x, _) = x`.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to perform a `map`ping where for each item in the list you map it to its age.

You can do this with the [**`map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`** function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map), so this will look like:

```
allAges = map …
```

where I leave filling in `…` as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

you can solve it recursively like:

```
allages [] = []
allages ((_,x,_):xs) = x : allages xs
```

Answer (score 0):

> *I know that I can use*
>
> ```
> age (_,x,_) = x
> ```
>
> But it only works with tuples and not a tuple inside a list.

Why are you saying this? Surely if you know that

```
age   (_,x,_)  =  x
```

then you also know that

```
ages [(_,x,_)] = [x]
```

and

```
ages [(_,x,_), (_,y,_)]          = [x,y]
ages [(_,x,_), (_,y,_), (_,z,_)] = [x,y,z]
....
```

etc. And since we've already established that

```
ages [         (_,y,_), (_,z,_)] = [  y,z]
ages [                  (_,z,_)] = [    z]
```

so that surely

```
ages [                         ] = [     ]
```

we can just write down these equations,

```
ages [                       ] = [                               ]
ages ([(_,x,_)] ++ moreTuples) = ages [(_,x,_)] ++ ages moreTuples
```

and since we know that `ages [(_,x,_)] = [x]`, it's

```
ages [                       ] = [                               ]
ages ([(_,x,_)] ++ moreTuples) = [        x   ] ++ ages moreTuples
```

so now all that's left to make it *valid Haskell syntax* is to rewrite the first equation's argument using the `:` operator, along the lines of

```
      [   a   ] ++ moreTuples ==
          a     :  moreTuples
```

and you're done.

So in the end you *did* know how to do this.